How to see example spans in collector quick set with debug/tracez?
Following this page: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/quick-start/
I followed the steps 1-5 in the collector quick-start and all is good, I see the spans in the output file with names lets-go and okey-dokey.
However when I follow step 6 (Open http://localhost:55679/debug/tracez) I don't see any span names with lets-go or okey-dokey. Or any counts that align with the number of spans I created.
This is what I see.
https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/3769612/384445538-da2f1502-83e3-4077-a013-c4d6864c144f.png?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.k-BLXBDdYny_2cBuOQUg3LJCvGBy3KD5RhiEOdTefCU
I was expecting to see span names of lets-go and okey-dokey in the list.
